# oracle dynamic query fetch cursor variables through sql

Tags: sql, database, oracle, plsql

Little help needed. i have a dynamic query that outputs 4 column names and two table names into 6 cursor variables. Now i need to use the cursor variables to select the first 4 columns and then from the two table names using the cursor variables since those contain the data think something with a fetch through query using a variable that contains the query but i don’t know how to go about that. here’s what i have now i just need to fetch the cursor variables and runt hem into a query

```
DECLARE
arow            VARCHAR2 (1000);

column1         VARCHAR2 (50);
column2         VARCHAR2 (50);
column3         VARCHAR2 (50);
column4         VARCHAR2 (50);
table1          VARCHAR2 (50);
table2          VARCHAR2 (50);
match           VARCHAR2 (50);
match1          VARCHAR2 (50);
sql_statement   VARCHAR2 (500);
BEGIN
FOR arow IN (SELECT   column_name_old,
                     column_name_new,
                     column_name_old_2,
                     column_name_new_2,
                     table_name_old,
                     table_name_new
              FROM   A550003.META_DATA_TABLE)
LOOP
  sql_statement :=
        'INSERT'
     || ' '
     || 'INTO'
     || ' '
     || 'a550003.MATCH_TABLE'
     || ' '
     || 'SELECT '
     || arow.column_name_old
     || ', '
     || arow.column_name_new
     || ', '
     || 'DECODE( '
     || arow.column_name_old
     || ', '
     || arow.column_name_new
     || ','
     || '1'
     || ','
     || '0)'
     || 'AS'
     || ' '
     || 'MATCH'
     || ','
     || arow.column_name_old_2
     || ', '
     || arow.column_name_new_2
     || ','
     || 'DECODE( '
     || arow.column_name_old_2
     || ', '
     || arow.column_name_new_2
     || ','
     || '1'
     || ','
     || '0)'
     || 'AS'
     || ' '
     || 'MATCH1'
     || ' FROM '
     ||' '
     || arow.table_name_old
     || ', '
     || arow.table_name_new
     || ' WHERE '
     || arow.column_name_old
     || '='
     || arow.column_name_new
     || '(+)';
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE (sql_statement);

 EXECUTE IMMEDIATE sql_statement;

  COMMIT;
END LOOP;
END;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all you sql_statement is wrong. You should set the value of this variable to sth like this (when you will get all needed names):

```
sql_statement := 'SELECT '
                 || column1 
                 || ', ' 
                 || column2 
                 || ', ' 
                 || column3 
                 || ', ' 
                 || column4 
                 || ' FROM ' 
                 || table1
                 || ', '
                 || table2
                 || ' WHERE '
                 || -- JOIN_CONDITION
```

And then you can use EXECUTE IMMEDIATE statement:

```
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE sql_statement
             INTO col1_val
                 ,col2_val
                 ,col3_val
                 ,col4_val
                 ;
```

Of course variables col[1..4]_val have to be declared.

Also watch out for SQL Injection.

Comment: hey kpater thanks for your response sorry i havnt used dynamic sql a ton. i have edited my original post query and i did't lnow if it looks right. i get missing expression by the execute immediatly, i am not really sure if thats where it should go since its reading from my curosor values

Comment: 1. Try to formatting you code before putting in the question. 2. You shoud build your query (set sql_statement variable) after fetching data from the cursor. 3. Your select is returning 4 columns so you shouldn't put tab1_val, and tab2_val in the `INTO` part of you `EXECUTE IMMEDIATE` statement. 4. If you are using INTO then your select should return always one record. If you are expecting more results you should use BULK COLLECT INTO and variable which is a collection.

Comment: my above code compiles but nothing actually inserts into the match table

Comment: You are changing your question all the time... There was nothing before about inserting data to the table... I don't know you data so it is hard to say why nothing is inserted to your table.

Comment: As @Wernfried wrote use `DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE (sql_statement);` for debugging. You can also put some output of this statement in the question.

Comment: hey guys okay thanks for the help i got it all set and i know it can actually run the queries but when i actually try my last strange issue is a Encountered the symbol "EXECUTE" when expecting one of the following: right by my execute immediate. i know the queries are correct and can actually pushed data to my new table as i can tell by the dbms output but i cant actually get it to push into the table becaus eof the strange error any thoughts. i edited the top to my newest code

Comment: In the last line of you sql_statement sing ';' should be after closing quote, not before: `|| '(+)';` instead of `|| '(+);'`

Comment: thanksman i forgot i added that to make sure the dbms output looked right and not neccesarily the code. thanks for all your help much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

It must be this:

```
sql_statement := 'SELECT ' 
    || column1 || ', ' || column2 || ', ' || column3 || ', ' || column4 
    || ' FROM ' || table1 || ', ' || table2 
    || ' WHERE ' || column1 ||'=' ||column2||'(+)'; 
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE sql_statement INTO col1_val, col2_val, col3_val, col4_val;
```

or preferably

```
sql_statement := 'SELECT ' 
    || column1 || ', ' || column2 || ', ' || column3 || ', ' || column4 
    ||' FROM '||table1||' LEFT OUTER JOIN '||table2||' ON '||column1||'='||column2;
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE sql_statement INTO col1_val, col2_val, col3_val, col4_val;
```

For debugging `DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE (sql_statement);` will be usefull!

Then you don't need a Ref-Cursor, simply do:

```
BEGIN
   For aRow in (SELECT * FROM a550003.meta_data_table) LOOP
      sql_statement := 'SELECT '||aRow.column1||','||aRow.column2 ...
   END LOOP;
END;
```

Comment: hey Wernfried thanks for the help it seems that is exactly what i need. i got it working and now if i wanted to have the sql_staement write to a table would i do somthing like a instert into before the (for arow part), i also need to now execute the sql_statement as if i was just putting it into a editor tab and running the query. Now the query i need is in the DBMS output but now i need to get that into somthing i can actually run it